# Acquire List of Zillow Links from a list of addresses

Tags: screen-scraping, zillow

I would like to acquire a list of Zillow links for each address that I have on a spreadsheet.  Ultimately, I want to be able to access the Zillow listing for each address without having to input the address into Zillow manually.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Zillow seems to have [an API](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm) which might be the best way to get access to that data.  Otherwise, using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) might be your next best mechanism.